# How to create a query to compare two exact results of two additional queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I´m creating a data model to register the SERVICES that an EMPLOYEE is able to perform based on its list of COURSES completed (COURSE_ID). To do this I have two data tables: EMPLOYEES and SERVICES. And I have two map tables: one table to relate the COURSES completed by EMPLOYEE and another table to relate the COURSES required by a SERVICE.

The data tables looks like this:

EMPLOYEES:

```
EMP_ID   NAME
=============
1        Joe
2        Bob
3        Rob
```

SERVICES:

```
SERV_ID   SERVICE
====================
1         Install
2         Configure
3         Manage
```

The relation or map tables look like this:

EMPLOYEE_COURSES

```
EMP_ID   COURSE_ID
==================
1        3
1        5
1        6
2        5
3        4
```

SERVICE_COURSES

```
SERV_ID  COURSE_ID
==================
1        3
1        5
1        6
2        3
3        4
```

The query result that I want to produce should look like this where only SERVICES 1 and 3 are shown since only two EMPLOYEES have the required courses by SERVICE:

```
SERV_ID  EMP_ID  SERVICE    NAME
================================
1        1       Install    Joe
2        1       Configure  Joe
3        3       Manage     Rob
```

Any help is appreciate.
Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a straight join between all four tables to me.

Comment: Also, why does Joe not have Configure listed in your example output? He's done course 3, which lists Install and Configure as the relevant services?

Comment: I tried the JOINs but in the output its not filtering if all the required courses are met. In other words the idea is to compare required list of courses by service with list of courses of engineer and if the list match shows the output. Another way to see my example is:

Employee Courses:
Joe (3,5,6)
Bob (5)
Rob (4)

Service Required Courses:
Install (3,5,6)
Configure (3)
Manage (4)

Joe is able to do the “Install” Service. Rob is able to do the “Manage” Service. Bob is not able to do any Service since He does n´t meet the required courses for any service.

Comment: I'm still not sure I get your logic. Unless maybe you mean if there are 3 courses for a service, the employee is only matched if they have taken all 3 services? And doesn't Joe meet the requirements for Install? If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks for yor help @Boneist. Yes, you were right. Joe is also able to do the "Manage" service since Manage service only requires course_id 3 and Joe has it in his list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
with     employees as (select 1 emp_id, 'Joe' name from dual union all
                       select 2 emp_id, 'Bob' name from dual union all
                       select 3 emp_id, 'Rob' name from dual),
          services as (select 1 serv_id, 'Install' service from dual union all
                       select 2 serv_id, 'Configure' service from dual union all
                       select 3 serv_id, 'Manage' service from dual),
  employee_courses as (select 1 emp_id, 3 course_id from dual union all
                       select 1 emp_id, 5 course_id from dual union all
                       select 1 emp_id, 6 course_id from dual union all
                       select 2 emp_id, 5 course_id from dual union all
                       select 3 emp_id, 4 course_id from dual),
   service_courses as (select 1 serv_id, 3 course_id from dual union all
                       select 1 serv_id, 5 course_id from dual union all
                       select 1 serv_id, 6 course_id from dual union all
                       select 2 serv_id, 3 course_id from dual union all
                       select 3 serv_id, 4 course_id from dual),
     ---- end of mimicking your tables and data
          svc_main as (select serv_id,
                              course_id,
                              count(course_id) over (partition by serv_id) svc_course_count
                       from   service_courses)
select sc.serv_id,
       ec.emp_id,
       svc.service,
       emp.name
from   svc_main sc
       inner join employee_courses ec on (ec.course_id = sc.course_id)
       inner join employees emp on (ec.emp_id = emp.emp_id)
       inner join services svc on (svc.serv_id = sc.serv_id)
group by sc.serv_id,
         ec.emp_id,
         svc.service,
         emp.name,
         sc.svc_course_count
having count(ec.course_id) = sc.svc_course_count
order by ec.emp_id,
         sc.serv_id;

   SERV_ID     EMP_ID SERVICE   NAME
---------- ---------- --------- ----
         1          1 Install   Joe 
         2          1 Configure Joe 
         3          3 Manage    Rob
```

N.B. I am assuming that there is a unique constraint on (emp_id, course_id) in employe_courses and on (serv_id, course_id) in service_courses. If you could have multiple rows for the same emp_id/serv_id per course_id, then you'll have to put "distinct" inside the counts in my query.

Basically, what I'm doing is first of all, finding out how many courses there are per service (done via an analytic function in the svc_main subquery), and then join everything together before finding out how many courses per service for each employee. Then it's just a case of choosing the employees that have the same number of courses for a given service that matches with the number of courses required for that service.

Comment: Thanks @Boniest. The problem is that the course IDs are services are not static it could be difficult to maintain. I tried the two queries with no exist to discard the non-complaints from Anton Zaviriukhin and it seems to works fine

Comment: What would be difficult to maintain? You realise that where I've used the union all'd select from duals is just to make up the data for the rest of the query, right? You wouldn't need them because you have the actual tables. I.e. your version of the query would start "with svc_main as ..."

Comment: You are right @Boniest. Thanks. I did a quick look before but now I tested and this options works just fine too! It will help me a lot with similar queries

Comment: Good! You should test both solutions for performance before deciding which one you finally settle for, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Just start joining tables.

```
 select yourfields
 from employees join employee_courses using (emp_id)
 join service_courses using (course_id)
 join services using (serv_id)
 etc
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Bracuk. The problem with the JOINs is that is shows records without considering if the JOIN matches all the rows. When there is just one common ID it shows the record anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.emp_id,e.name,s.serv_id,s.service
from employees e
join employee_courses ec on e.emp_id = ec.emp_id
join service_courses sc on sc.course_id = ec.course_id
join services s on s.serv_id = sc.serv_id
```

The JOIN conditions would give you the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you may use something like this:

```
select distinct s.serv_id, e.EMP_ID, s.service, e.name
  from EMPLOYEES e
  join EMPLOYEE_COURSES ec on ec.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
  join SERVICE_COURSES sc on sc.COURSE_ID = ec.COURSE_ID
  join SERVICES s on s.SERV_ID = sc.SERV_ID
 where 
   not exists (select * 
                 from SERVICE_COURSES sc1 
                 left join EMPLOYEE_COURSES ec1 
                   on sc1.COURSE_ID = ec1.COURSE_ID
                  and ec1.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
                where s.SERV_ID = sc1.SERV_ID
                  and ec1.EMP_ID is null)
```

Here we select distinct employee-service pairs (by joining 4 tables).
Distinct is required to avoid 3 records for serv_id=1, emp_id=1 (you may use "group by" instead). 
And then filter out employees that doesn't meet criteria.
We need only employees that has all courses for corresponding service.
In other words we need only employess that doesn't have records in
service_courses without corresponding employee_courses record (so no service_course missed).
This can be done in different ways.
For example by outer joining EMPLOYEE_COURSES of this employee to all service_courses of this service - if we found at least one miss of EMPLOYEE_COURSES record, then this employee should be filtered out.

(sorry for eny typo, I didn't have a chance to check this query in databse)

Comment: Thanks Anton. This one works just as I needed. No typos at all